# Interpolate between multiple series in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZiIx.png)

I have a graph with multiple series. Lets call them blue, red, grey and yellow. So, given a point on the red graph, I want to find the corresponding x-value of the blue graph. So, if it was in the real world, I would have drawn a line on the point on the red line horizontally. It would meet the blue line. From this point I would draw line to vertically which would meet the x-axis and I would have collected the value. How do i do this in excel.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your image is some type of trendline in excel. If you click on your curve and go to trendline options you can click on display equation on chart.

You can then build those equations into various cells and then when you input a number in one cell the formulas will calculate the solution.

[image]

The less manual way is to use a formula (e.g., `=LINEST`) to calculate the coefficients based on your data and then build your equation using those coefficients. I do not know if excel has formula equivalents to all trendlines in the chart functions.

Comment: The problem is I am not looking for a trend line or forecast values. I have the graph then and there. Its just both points have same y values, I have the x value of one, I just need to find the unknown x value.

Comment: So tell us how the red curve and the blue curve were created in your picture? Did you start from data points? Was a best fit curve then used to get your blue curve and red curve? What is the formula for these best fit curves? Finally, if you took a Y value from the best fit red curve and plugged it in the best fit curve from the blue line what would you get?

Comment: I dont know if you are acquainted with ELISA. But, essentially for a range of concentration of a given sample we get absorbance values. So it is a absorbance against concentration graph. Yes its a best fit. I just selected the data and inserted graph on Excel. In this case we have a standard and three samples. The blue line is the standard curve. So for a given value of y in the sample, i want to know the x value of the blue curve, the standard. I think it makes sense. We essentially can use any software program but excel is free for us so.....

Comment: OK, if ELISA just gave you a graphic image then you are pretty much stuck with eyeballing it. If you can get ELISA to tell you what that best fit curve was that it applied, then you can put that in excel to calculate any X for any Y you plug in. The only other option I can think of is to replot X and Y from your ELISA graph (by the eyeball method) into an excel table and use excel to graph it, my suggested answer would then apply.